# Show last autogenerated File Number in MsgBox after an Address has been entered through an InputBox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I created a button that when pressed will create an InputBbox to enter an address into a table. Once the address is entered a file number is generated.

The table I created has a File_Number Column that will AutoNumber once the Address is input.

```vb
Private Sub Command39_Click()

Dim dbsFileGen As DAO.Database
Dim NewAddress As DAO.Recordset
Dim AddNew As String
Dim FileNum As DAO.Recordset
Dim FileN As Integer

Set dbsFileGen = CurrentDb
Set NewAddress = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("dbo_File_Generator", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
Set FileNum = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("dbo_File_Generator", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

AddNew = InputBox("Please enter the building address.")

NewAddress.AddNew
NewAddress!Address = AddNew
NewAddress.Update

End Sub
```

I tried the .MoveLast Function to display the last number in the table however it shows the second to last number.

Comment: Why are you doing this as opposed to using a bound form? Depending on how you plan to use this address info, might be best to put address parts into separate fields. Posted code does not show use of MoveLast. How would you expect that to show the new record on form?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since this is only ONE column value, then the inputbox idea is ok. (but, for any more fields, you would want to pop up a data entry form as "dialog".
Ok, so the code has to do TWO steps:

```
  add the row - save it
  THEN get/grab the new auto number ID column
```

So, code should and would look like this:

```
Sub AddOneSQL()

    Dim AddNew     As String
    AddNew = InputBox("Please enter the building address.")
    
    If AddNew = "" Then
       ' user did not enter anything - exit the routine - bail out
       Exit Sub
    End If

    ' if we get here, then user did enter somthing, so we NOW start our data
    ' operations code. (don't start before the input box, since what then if
    ' user does not enter, or hits cancel - we bail out as per above.

    Dim NewAddress  As DAO.Recordset
    Dim MyNewRowPK  As Long
    
    Set NewAddress = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("dbo_File_Generator", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
     
     NewAddress.AddNew
     NewAddress!Address = AddNew
     NewAddress.Update           ' this will generate the new auto number id
     
     ' now get autonubmer ID - unfortantly DAO has the nasty feature (only when addding)
     ' that .Update will cause the record poitner to move off (not valid), so we move back
     NewAddress.bookMark = NewAddress.LastModified
     
     MyNewRowPK = NewAddress("ID")     ' replace "id" with your autonumber column name
     NewAddress.Close
     
     MsgBox "new autonumber id = " & MyNewRowPK
     
End Sub
```